# Sitecore GEOIP Issue with load balancer

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-services-client

In a project, I have implemented Sitecore GEOIP to get visitor's country information. In local, it was working fine but when we deployed it in Production environment, GEOIP was not able to get visitor's IP because it works under load balancer. So it returns **load balancer IP** instead of actual visitor's IP.
I tried some suggestions like in the link,  http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2013/09/get-users-ip-address-in-load-balancing.html
 and

http://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2015/08/setting-up-sitecores-geolocation-lookup.html

But none of them worked for me.

So can anyone please suggest some solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you able to get the right X-Forwarded-For IP address on the server?

Comment: No, when I tried                                                                     
    Response.Write(" || HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);                   its returning blank and when i tried                                                  
    <setting name="Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader" value="X-Forwarded-For" />                                                                                      in Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config   its returning Load Balancer ip itself

Comment: This means that the issue is with the Load Balancer, not with Sitecore. Since you're not getting back the IP. Unless the Load Balancer is adding the IP to the request, there's nothing Sitecore can do.

Comment: Are you using ARR to handle the load balancing, or is this in Azure?

Comment: Sorry right now I don't have any information about Load Balancer but I'll find out.

Comment: Have you gotten this to work yet?

Comment: Yes, we had to change settings in load balancer. After that its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

For most load balancers it is indeed the following case sensitive setting:

```
<setting name="Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader" value="X-Forwarded-For" />
```

However, you may want to check with your particular load balancer as sometimes they vary.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. Currently I have passed value in above format itself  so now should I try all with capitals letters or something else?

Comment: Hi Arun, if that format didn't work, then my next step would be to find out exactly what your load balancer is, what software it is running and see what that particular load balancer is wanting.

Comment: OK, Next I'll do the same and update here what was the issue. Thank you very much :).